# Prove f(x) <= x for all x>=0 if f ' (x) <= -2 for all x and f(0) = 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The title basically states the whole question..I was trying to invoke the Mean Value Theorem on it but it hasn't worked..I was wondering if I'm supposed to solve it some other way. I just need hints, please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is continuously differentable, 
$$ f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)\, dt \le 0 + \int_0^x -2\, dt = -2x, \qquad x \ge 0.$$

Choose $x > 0$.
Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $(0,x)$ and continuous on $[0,x]$.  Then there is some point $c\in(0,x)$ so that
$$f'(c) = {f(x)-f(0)\over x} ={f(x)\over x}$$
Since $f'(c) \le -2$, 
${f(x)\over x}\le -2$
so $f(x) \le -2x$.

Comment: I can't use the integral yet..I'm supposed to solve it with only differentiation techniques..

Comment: In that case, apply the Mean value theorem.

Comment: MVT is what I've tried..but $f'(x) <= -2$ for all x so I can't set it directly equal to -2, can I?

Comment: See edits.  It uses MVT.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have one question..if $f(x) <= -2x$ how can we conclude that $f(x) <= x$ for all $x$?

Comment: Easily; $x \ge -2x$ for all $x$. My result is mucho stronger.

Comment: Thank you again..and sorry for being an idiot..

Comment: This place is created to help you learn. "Studying mathematics means having plenty of opportunity to feel stupid" -- Steven McAdam (prof of math, UTexas/Austin).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Apply the MVT to $(0,x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = f(x)+2x$.
Then
$g'(x) = f'(x)+2
\le 0$
and
$g(0) = 0$.

$g(x)$ is decreasing
since $g'(x) \le 0$,
so
$g(x) \le 0$.

Therefore
$f(x) = g(x)-2x
\le -2x$.

The result that
$g(0) = 0$
and
$g'(x) \le 0$
implies that
$g(x) \le 0$
needs the mvt,
but this way seems
easier to me.